# Incrementing a pointer in C causing Segmentation Fault even if it is within array size

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a[12];
  for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
    a[i]=i*i+1;
  }
  int *p=a;
  for(;p<(p+10);p++){
    printf("%d",*p);
  }
}
```

This is returning segmentation fault. If I use a new line in printf, it's returning junk characters and then a Segmentation fault.
I'm using this version of Compiler:

Configured with: `--prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p < (p + 10);` will not work.  It will keep forever looping, forever incrementing `p`, because each time `p` incremens, so does the expression `p + 10` increment.  It is like a kitten trying to catch its tail.

Eventually `p` starts pointing to memory outside of your program, which is illegal to access, and that's why it crashes.

Your observation that if you use a new line in printf, it's returning junk characters and then a Segmentation fault is wrong.  It's returning 12 lines containing the exact values that you expected, then garbage, as and then a segmentation fault happens.

Without a newline, the output of your program is being cached in an internal buffer waiting either for a newline to be emitted or for the program to terminate, but the crash happens before a newline is emitted, so you never get to see any output.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I just started with C, silly mistake :(.